# Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, shortcuts

In 10.04, I had a lot of keyboard shortcuts defined using <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Mod4</kbd> and one single other key,

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> ran Opera
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> opened Nautilus pointing to my Work folder, etc.

In 11.04, these do not seem to work -- only <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> works to run the terminal, and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> successfully runs Nautilus.

Is there some way I can get these to function again?

Adding them in *Keyboard Shortcuts* does not work, and neither does adding commands in *CompizConfig Settings Manager*.

Comment: Are you adding commands in the Commands plugin for ccsm? It works fine for me: just make sure to remember to set both the command and they key-binding :P

Comment: Yep, I did that, as I wrote, and set the keybindings, but it didn't work until I removed the Launcher binding, as instructed below.

Comment: Follow-up for 12.04: I encountered a problem updating to 12.04, namely that some shortcuts did again not work and some had been altered. Under System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts, some of my custom shortcuts had been changed from `Super+<key>` to `Mod4+Super+Hyper+<key>`. These wtill worked, so did all with other modifiers, i.e. `Ctrl+Super+<key>`. Pure `Super+<key>` did not work when set in that dialog. Setting them in CCSM using the Commands plugin does work (in conjunction with the answer below).

Comment: I must say that I'd really appreciate if the Dash/Launcher <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcuts could be modifiable individually. I generally like the concept, but I'd like to live without several shortcuts like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> that I'm used to use in terminator.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This happens because in Natty <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Mod4</kbd> is a shortcut to the Unity panel. You can change that in Compiz.

1. Install the [compizconfig-settings-manager[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) package.
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `about:config` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Unity configuration.
3. Change the shortcut for *Key to show the launcher* as you like to free your <kbd>Super</kbd> key:

   [image]

In this example I've changed from <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Now your mod key is free to use as you like.

Comment: One downside to this is that Super+(number) no longer works to quickly switch between apps, at least not on my Azerty keyboard.

Comment: You are right .

Comment: You may also find the first answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/378037/keyboard-shortcuts-how-to-see-a-list-of-them helpful to see what your key mappings are.

Comment: I cannot find the equivalent to this in ubuntu 14.04, would you know where that would be?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 you can assign "Super"+"Key" to a shortcut without needing to change de launcher shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

To do this without installing anything and without having to navigate the unfamiliar menus.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type `gnome-terminal` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_launcher '<Super>a'` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Change the `a` after `<Super>` to whichever key you prefer.

Note that `s` and `w` are already taken, and I wouldn't recommend using `l` because that's often used for lock screen.

Comment: Running `gnome-terminal` is recommended because you can't paste into the `Alt+F2` dialog.  [Bug 736222](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/736222).

Answer (score 0):

Simpler from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129755/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-in-12-04): *In System Settings / Keyboard / Typing tab / Layout Settings link (at the bottom) / Layouts tab / Options button / "Alt/Win key behaviour", choose Meta is mapped to Left Win key.*