# How to remap keyboard shortcuts in Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**  > [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)

I am aware of how to change the shortcut to focus the Launcher with CompizConfig Settings Manager, so this is a different question from [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)

My default installation (11.04) has assigned <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to Firefox and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to Chrome. I would like to assign <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to Firefox and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to Chrome.

*How can I do this?*

Comment: Did you try 'keyboard shortcuts' to map your application?

Comment: @desgua no, that's a different question; see my comment to user14955's answer

Comment: @akaihola you are right.

Comment: this is a dup of which question? Were you able to solve this? In addiction I think achieving the same effect that super+# does that switches to an app or open a new instance if there's none already loaded, may be something harder to do, but definitely something I would like to know. :)

Comment: @snoop: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/36910/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Change the shortcut "Key to show the launcher" in Compiz Config Manager. You can read how to change: [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

I change it for example to Ctrl+Meta (Ctrl+Windows). Now the shortcuts of Unity are Ctrl+Meta+1, Ctrl+Meta+2.... and the old shortcuts with Meta Key (Windows key) are located on Power Off key> System Settings> Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: I believe the question was about changing application hotkeys in the Unity Launcher, not accessing the GNOME shortcuts. The difference is that while you can assign GNOME shortcuts to launch new instances of applications, Launcher shortcuts will focus an existing application window if one exists.