# Super (windows) key no longer works in programs

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)

Using programs that require the super key in a shortcut combination is now overridden by Unity. For example, Terminator, which uses Super-G to group commandwindows can no longer be used as the menu keeps popping up removing the focus on the Terminator window. How to remedy this?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key/39026

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :
a) Please install CCSM (Compizconf-settings-manager), if not already installed.
b) Then open it and find the Ubuntu Unity plugin, which will be checked on.
c) Click on it and there you will find "Key to show the launcher", which is set as the Super key.
d) You can change it to some other combination like Shift+Super key combination.
e) Then from Control Center (You can find it by clicking on the shutdown icon at the top right corner at the screen and selecting System settings), search for keyboard shortcuts.
f) Now you can set the key combinations as per your choice for the Super keys.

Hope it works for you.