# How do I bind 'Menu key' to right 'Win key'?

Tags: unity, keyboard, menu, xmodmap

I have a keyboard with two "Win" keys but without "Menu" key. I'd like to bind my right Win as Menu. I tried do used xev in terminal and get keycode for .Xmodmap file but can't take code of right Win. Just always open system menu of ubuntu. How I can do it?

Comment: I've answered a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/a/1323635/935982 that might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

This should be do-able using `xmodmap`.

First, find the keycode for your Win-key: Enter terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+T`, and type `xev`. Now press your Win-key and note down the keycode shown.

(If you have problems obtaining the keycode, you may first have to change the Win-key from being a one-key shortcut for Dash. How this can be done [has been answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key).

Once you obtain the keycode, say `xxx`, execute in terminal

```
xmodmap -e "keycode xxx = Menu"
```

This should map you Win-key to Menu. You can test it using e.g. `xev` again: a little after the keycode, it should now write something like `(keysym 0xff67, Menu)`.

To automate setting it on startup, see [e.g. this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried the keyboard preference mapping under Gnome, you should give it a look.  This doesn't fit your description exactly, but it might work well enough.

From type, type **keyboard** to go to the keyboard preferences.  Select the **Layouts** tab, then choose Win/Alt behavior.

[image: keyboard preferences]

Comment: I tried it before ask :) But nothing works.

Answer (score -2):

The `Win` key in Ubuntu is a modifier. It treated just like the `Alt` and `Ctrl` keys and as such cannot be used as a standalone key.

Comment: It is used as a "standalone" key in both 11.04 and 11.10. It does open the "main menu", which is dash in Unity, but it's also used in combination with other keys. Your answer is wrong. -1