# How to remap the context menu to another key in linux?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I just purchased a Lenovo thinkpad and I am so proud of everything in it. It feels just as rock solid as the Linux kernel :P.

The problem is that Lenovo decided to remove the context menu key that is the key that does the right click stuff. They replaced it by a print screen key. My keyboard has its numeric part with some buttons above it. There is a magnifying glass key that I would like to remap to open the context menu or be the right click key. Is it possible to do this?

I've tried searching for other related questions but I only found Q&As on how to add options to the Nautilus context menu. I want to to map a physical key of my keyboard to open this menu. Just like before. It also appears that Dell is dropping this key in their inspiron keyboard. I dont know whats going on since I use the keyboard more than mouse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please install xbindkeys with `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`.  Then in a terminal run `xbindkeys -k` and type the key you want to change.  Can you add the output to your question?

Comment: "NoCommand"
    m:0x50 + c:46
    Mod2+Mod4 + l

Comment: Who would want a Print Screen key where they'd expect a Menu key? I seriously wonder how drunk you are allowed to show up to work at Lenovo. Anyway, note that you don't need an `.Xmodmap` generated by `xmodmap -pke` to start with, you can as well just put your binding in an empty file. Also, look at what @Baha_hi found out below.

Answer (score 19):

It's a little bit complicated but you can do it. Follow these steps:

### Detect keycode

1. Run `xev` to detect the keycode:

   ```
   xev | grep keycode

           state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
           state 0x0, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff67, Menu), same_screen YES,
           state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
   ```
2. Press the key you want to reconfigure. The output in the terminal will show you the `keycode` (be careful, might have several).

### Test mapping

1. Set new mapping temporarily, for me it's `keycode 107`:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode  107 = Return NoSymbol Return"
   ```

If the key behave as expected, you can save the config.

### Save your config

1. Save your current keymap table to your `$HOME`, to override the defau:

   ```
   xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
2. Create or edit `~/.xinitrc` to load your configuration:

   ```
   $EDITOR ~/.xinitrc
   ```
3. Add following lines

   ```
   if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
           /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
   fi
   ```

### Enjoy

Most of the information above comes from [ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap).

Comment: There is a problem. When I press the button 'l' is marked. I checked it at xev and it give me the 46 keycode which is assigned to the L l letter. Maybe it doesnt have a keycode a take one.

Comment: @Jhonnytunes. Check that your keyboard layout is correct. You can change your model typing ` sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Comment: Still the same behaivor.  I tried different thinkpad models and nothing.

Comment: BTW my thinkpad is an E530c and doesnt appear in the keyboard list.

Comment: If [this](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/WW/products/splitter/notebooks/ThinkPad/Edge/gallery/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-edge-e530c-overhead-keyboard-view-4L.jpg) is your keyboard layout, maybe the key next to «Delete» is actually «Context menu» (the function you are looking for). Otherwise, reconfigure another key or ask directly Lenovo's desk which layout you should choose.

Comment: Thats my keyboard. The key besides delete opens the calculator.

Comment: I try to remap the Calculator to the context menu and doesnt work. I did the xmodmap step and lookup the Calculator word in the file using Vim. I switch the keymap code of the calculator with this text "Menu NoSymbol Menu" then I did the xmodmap .Xmodmap and instead of open the calculator that button just do nothing now. I also try to write XF86Menu as was in the Xmodmap File. This is the generated file by xmodmap by default: http://pastebin.com/ZAGQDMxX.

Comment: Sorry but the keycode of the calculator was the 148. The file I uploaded was modified.

Comment: I noticed that you xmodmap lists keycode 135 as «Menu NoSymbol Menu NoSymbol Menu». Maybe this is the way to do it.

Comment: Alternatively, try in terminal «xmodmap -e "keycode 148 = Menu"» and see if it works.

Comment: Negative http://pastebin.com/iH60vEL7

Comment: If the key you want to remap is the PrintScreen one, there might be a screenshot application bound to it which prevents the xev to capture the scancode. See the [related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412395/trying-to-remap-prtsc-key-in-laptop-no-keycode?rq=1) on how to disable it first.

Answer (score 13):

I found [here](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=104959) that using: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> opens the context menu.

I know it's not the best solution but I thought it could help for temporary use!

P.S: I have e530c too, and I tested this on Debian 7 (Wheezy).

Comment: on ubuntu 20 it opens application menu, which is the one that is shown when you right click on title bar of an application

Comment: Did you ever found a way to rebind the shift + F10 keybind?

Comment: @ManuelMartinez I didn't try that.

Answer (score 5):

I recently acquired a Lenovo E550 and had the same problem, I solved it by using `xte` (from `xautomation`) along with `xmodmap`.

## Why the other answers won't work entirely?

1. [@Ed Villegas](https://askubuntu.com/a/234681/155835) (nor [@Null Pointer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968398/155835)) answer won't work because some of the keys located above the numeric part are not unique keys by themself (*e.g.* the lock key is related to the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combination). When `xev` is used to try to find the lock key keycode it returns both the <kbd>Super</kbd> and the <kbd>L</kbd> keycodes, you just have to interpret the `xev` output line by line.
2. For [@Bahax](https://askubuntu.com/a/569005/155835) and [@John Finegan](https://askubuntu.com/a/587881/155835): <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is a context menu key, it doesn't work in all the applications and it doesn't provide the same functions as <kbd>Menu</kbd>. If you select a file in the file explorer and press  <kbd>Menu</kbd> the context menu for the file itself should pop-up, this does not happen with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> combination, it would provide a context menu for the window instead.
3. [@Danial Behzadi](https://askubuntu.com/a/386221/155835) takes a similar approach to the people in the 2nd item, but linking the keyboard combination to one key through a keystroke simulator, it will link the key to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and provide the same result.

## The answer that works

It is important to take into account that the key that is not present in the ThinkPad keyboard is the <kbd>Menu</kbd> (that is it's name), it is shown in the following picture:

[image: Menu key]

Although the key is not present, it's keycode should exist in your computer, you can find it by printing the keycode table with `xmodmap -pke | grep Menu` which should give you something like:

[image: xmodmap output]

With that in mind, install `xautomation` (in order to use `xte` for keystroke simulations) like in [@Danial Behzadi](https://askubuntu.com/a/386221/155835) answer:

> `sudo apt-get install xautomation`

And create a custom shortcut, in the *Trigger* press the key that you want to be the shortcut, and in the `Action` paste `xte 'key Menu'`. *Apply* and test.

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick for me.
For me the keycode for "PrtSc" button on my thinkpad is 107. I found that by "xev" tool in ubuntu.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  107 = Menu"
```

This is a temporary change.

You can make this permanent by adding this command to /etc/profile and it will execute everytime you boot and it will be a permanent change.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the way to do this after hours of tests and fails :D

First of all install xautomation:

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

Then head to the Shortcut tab of Keyboard section in Ubuntu System Settings. First go to Screenshots entry and remap the actions to another key or disable them if you want. I replaced PrtSc(Print) key by the Thinkpad black button (Launch1).

Now go to Custom Shortcuts section and add a shortcut. name it whatever you like, e.g. Menu. In Command field insert this:

```
xte 'keydown Shift_L' 'key F10' 'keyup Shift_L'
```

The work is done! It's working like a miracle ;)

Answer (score 3):

The following finally worked for me!

I'm have had the same problem with my Huawei Matebook 14 where the *menu key* is missing. Although I show how to map the menu operation to the *right control* (as I personally don't use it), this instruction works for any button.

The method works permanently.

Full guide (steps):

1. Know the key code you want to bind *Menu* command to. Execute :

   ```
   xev | grep keycode
   ```

   then press your button and remember the code. E.g. I want my `Right control` to call the context menu. I press it, and get the code: `105`.
2. Modify the keycodes configuration file:

   *Note: you need to do this as a super user.*

   *Optional but highly recommended! Make a backup of the configuration file:*

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev_back
   ```

   Open the file to edit:

   ```
   sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
   # or use any other editor e.g. 
   # sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
   ```

   Find a line with the original mapping (in my case, `<RCTL> = 105;`), comment it and add the new mapping of the menu command to the desired key (in my case, `<MENU> = 105;`)

   ```
   // the old mapping commented 
   // <RCTL> = 105;
   // the new mapping
   <MENU> = 105;
   ```

   save and close the file.
3. Logout/login (reboot) and enjoy!

Comment: I like this approach, too. For the Lenovo PrtSc key, this worked to obtain Menu funtionality on a Carbon X1 Gen 9 with Pop!_OS 21.04.

Comment: This should be the answer. xmodmap is deprecated and external software shouldn't be a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

## Tested on ubuntu 20.10

### Steps

#### Find menu key

1. Run `$ xmodmap -pk | grep "Menu"`
2. **Example** output

   ```bsh
   135     0xff67 (Menu)   0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff67 (Menu)   
   147     0x1008ff65 (XF86MenuKB) 0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff65 (XF86MenuKB)
   ```
3. If there are multiple results **try each of them** to make sure we have the correct key code
4. Try the key(s) from above result

- `$ xdotool key Menu`
- `$ xdotool key XF86MenuKB`

5. Remember which one worked, **for example** in my case "Menu" worked

#### Set the shortcut

- Go to Setting -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Scroll till you see **Custom shortcuts** -> Click on **+**
- A popup will open, fill as following

  - Name: give some logical name
  - Command: `xdotool key Menu`
  - Shortcut: as per you choice, **for example** in my case i assigned combination of right alt+printscreen

PS: install required packages if not already installed

Answer (score 0):

for gnome-shell, one just needs to edit this file: */usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc*.  and then reboot.

Comment: yeah this didn't work for me and requires more detail than what you've provided here.  Perhaps a working example.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the **Gnome3** shell (on **Ubuntu 20.04**) using `xte` or `xdotool`:

In system settings -> keyboard shortcuts, I create a custom shortcut:

```
xte 'keyup Print' 'key Menu'
```

or:

```
xdotool keyup Print key --clearmodifiers Menu
```

That I assign to the `Print` key.

Importantly, I have to include the command to release the key that triggers the command, (in this case the `Print` key).

If I want to assign a combination like `Shift+Print`, the `--clearmodifiers` option of `xdotool` does the same for any modifiers (`Shift`, `Ctrl`, etc.).

*Notes*:

- In the Unity shell (on Ubuntu 16.04), the keyup and modifiers part was not necessary, but in the Gnome3 shell (on Ubuntu 20.04), the shortcut will not work without it.
- Unlike using `xmodmap`, this persists after suspend.

**Extension: Combination with xmodmap**

I noticed that the xdotool command sometimes behaves in unexpected ways. E.g. while renaming a file in Nemo file manager, it will not show the context menu and cancel renaming.

So I followed [@Ed Villegas' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/234681/155835) to create an `xmodmap` configuration that is run on startup. To reactivate the remapping after suspend, I changed my keyboard shortcut (still assigned to the `Print` key) to execute:

```
/bin/bash -c "xdotool keyup Print key --clearmodifiers Menu && /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap"
```

In this way, the first use of the `Print` key after suspend will emulate the menu key using xdotool, while after that, it will be remapped to the menu key.

Answer (score 0):

4 simple lines in your shell startup i.e. `.zshrc`

```
mysetting=$(xmodmap -pke | grep 135)
if [ $mysetting != 'keycode 135 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R' ]; then
  sleep 4 && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap &
fi
```

In my case I keep hitting the menu button instead of right CTRL button. So I added this to my shell startup which also gets auto-launched on system boot via start-up items, opens my terminal. Yes there's a lag on the first terminal load, but after that, no such lag even if closing terminal and launching new one. For other remapping see previous answers to locate the mapping you need and you can modify this script accordingly.