# Trying to remap PrtSc key in laptop, no keycode

Tags: xorg, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xev

I'm trying to remap <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key to Insert (to use it in vim), with `/usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode XXX = Insert"` for it, I need to figure out what keycode for <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> is.

I'm doing `xev -event keyboard`
and pressing <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, but getting something strange

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967228 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Not sure not extract the keycode from this information.

Comment: xorg is interrupting those keys before they reach `xev`, you'll have to kill xorg to get the keycode and even then I'm not sure it will work. I also haven't found an efficient way of killing xorg that would enable me to catch the keycode.

Comment: @Seth actually in was just print screen application. Disabling it in cinnamon settings did the try. While this is not a general solution, it worked for me

Comment: Oh that's cool. PrtSc isn't usually this hard to deal with, so I'm glad it was easier than we thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out the PrtSc key was captured by some print screen application. Disabling it in cinnamon settings solved the problem. This also could work for gnome, too.

Comment: Actually, in Cinnamon settings (for Cinnamon 2.0 and 2.2) there is no place to disable the key. What helped me was to use `dconf-editor`, navigate to "org -> cinnamon -> settings-daemon -> plugins -> media-keys" and in the right-hand pane, change the line labeled screenshot to be empty (by default it says "Print") [via Linux Mint forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=152887).