# Custom keymapping is lost after rebooting

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've wanted to remap my print key on my Thinkpad T460p because Lenovo decided it would be more useful than the context menu ("Menu" which is basically the right mouse-) button.

It tried a solution from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234416/how-to-remap-the-context-menu-to-another-key-in-linux) and did the following:

Using

```
xev | grep keycode
```

and pressing the print key got me its keycode which is 107. The only difference to this thread is my keycode and I've set its value to "Menu". I've also edited .Xmodmap to keycode 107 = Menu NoSymbol Menu

It works setting it temporary but after a reboot it's gone. And yes I've edited the xinitrc too.

Is there an easier way maybe with the help of a GUI? I just want to use my print key as a context menu.

Thx everybody

Comment: Can be solved, but what is exactly the command you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long shot, but maybe adding `sleep 5` to `~/.xinitrc`, like this:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
        {
                sleep 5
                /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
        } &
fi
```

*Edit:*

It looks like `~/.xinitrc` is not sourced in Ubuntu (with lightdm). Try `~/.xsessionrc` instead.

Comment: That works. Thank you! Either it helped to add "sleep 5" or create the .xsessionrc file. It may also work adding sleep 5 to xinitrc but I didn't tried that :).

Edit: Cannot upvote your answer because of my low reputation

Comment: An example of a _good long headshot_ :)

Comment: Weird if I close my Laptop it is gone and does not work anymore :(
It works again if I reboot my Laptop

Comment: @Chronos90: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/661715/make-a-script-start-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-15-04-systemd