# How to figure out the keycode of and remap my right ctrl key?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a very unusual and very specific problem.

I'm trying to remap my right ctrl key to the [context menu button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) so that I can using it when navigating through files in nautilus instead of having to use the mouse and right click. When messing with unity settings in ubuntu 16.04 a couple days ago I was unable to get it working and don't remember what I changed.

I'm now running the latest ubuntu 17.04 with gnome desktop and wayland on my dell xps 13 2016.

I tried looking into the following articles: { [Set Context Menu key to function as Right Control](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321510/set-context-menu-key-to-function-as-right-control), [How to remap the context menu to another key in linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234416/how-to-remap-the-context-menu-to-another-key-in-linux)}

- *I originally thought* I would be able to just get the keycode in the way that the first article describes but whenever I hit the `right ctrl` button, I get a context based window come up that takes precedence over whatever my process was and gives control back to the desktop environment. Because I don't know what's triggering this menu and I can't find the code for the right ctrl key I'm not sure how to remap it to the button I want it to be.
- I've also tried going into gnome keyboard settings and checking the box "Menu as right ctrl" but it did not work unfortunately.

Images attached here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR1tX.jpg

I've used dconf editor to swap the caps lock and escape keys, and I've [edited Xmodmap](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/archive/index.php/t-40766.html) before but I don't know how to find out the keycode so I can swap it to the one I want, but any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

here is my ~/.Xmodmap

```
remove Mod2 = Meta_L
add Mod1 = Meta_L

clear Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```