# Can you change what key is the right click modiefier

Tags: 16.04, chromebook

I’m have a chrome book that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on and was wondering if there was a way to change the modifier key for a right click. Usually it’s alt, but for some reason it is set to shift. I hate right clicking on a buttonless touch pad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remap the context menu to another key in linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234416/how-to-remap-the-context-menu-to-another-key-in-linux)

Comment: @earthmeLon This is not a duplicate. Here, reference is made to a key you press that turns a single click on the touchpad to a right-click action. In the post you indicated as duplicate, a key is being switched without the touchpad being involved.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Sorry to have missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a.f.a.i.k., it is not possible in Linux to configure a modifier key that, while pressed, causes a single click on the touchpad/mouse to be interpreted as a right-click. (Of course, a skilled developer likely might implemented such feature by going into the source code of the operating system).

There are some options you may explore whether they work for you:

- By default, a two-finger click should act as a right-click.
- You can enable "Area" to enable right-clicking by clicking in the bottom right area. Install 'gnome-tweaks', which is not installed by default on Ubuntu. On the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab, enable "Area" under "Mouse Click Emulation".
- In "Settings" - "Universal Access", you can enable "Simulated Secondary Click". Click the option "Click Assist". Now you can set up a delay before a single click (must be a physical click, not a "tap"), turns into a right click.
- Also in "Settings" - "Universal Access", you can enable "Mouse Keys". This allow you to control your mouse cursor using the keyboard, but requires the availability of a numerical keypad.

As you see in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234416/how-to-remap-the-context-menu-to-another-key-in-linux), you can call up a right-click menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. This, however, reacts to the position of the text cursor, and not to the position of the mouse cursor. Still, it can be useful in many situations to replace using mouse or touchpad.