# Reassign keyboard shortcuts for Unity "launcher"?

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)

How can I reassign the keyboard shortcuts for the Unity "launcher" (in Ubuntu 11.10beta1)  By default, the applications in the launcher are assigned Super-1, Super-2, etc.  I would like to use those key combinations for more common activities, and so would like to set the launcher to use Shift-Super-1, etc.  I can not find any configuration setting in Unity or the Compiz Settings Manager.

Answer (score 2):

I believe these shortcuts are hardcoded into Unity in Ubuntu 11.10, so without editing the source code and recompiling, this won't be possible.