# how to set different keys for showing dash and for showing keyboard shortcuts

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-dash, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)

I am using Oneiric and after using a few days I am happy with the Dash and Unity in general.   I have one minor problem I run into too many times.   Since the same button (super) is used for showing Dash (tap) and the launcher shorcuts (keep pressed), both actions end up mixed up much of the time.

I was wondering, is there is a way to have to different shortcuts for those 2 actions instead of using the same button?

Any hack will do for me.

Thank you.

Comment: This is maybe also a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/34145/236