# Is it possible to customize the Unity sidebar shortcuts to launch applications?

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcut-keys

Ok, my question might not be as clear as it should be, exclude my English. It is not my native tongue.

What happens:

When I press the Super key the sidebar appears and when I keep it pressed numbers appear on the icons and if I press them in combination with the Super key then the relative application gets loaded or the relative window gets evidenced. Unfortunately, this works only up to 0 (that is, 1 to 9, then 0) together with the s key (workspace selector) and t key (trash).

What I would like to know how to do, if possible:

Well, if there are enough icons to get to the 0 then other open windows or icons cannot be loaded using the Super key. Is there a way to change / customize this? For example, I could use the Super key in combination with g to load gedit (which would be as an icon in the sidebar).

I hope I've explained myself well.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key Have a look and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: That's not exactly what I intend. You see I don't really want a shortcut to load or an application or highlight its window (those this could work indirectly). I want to do that when an application shortcut is present in Unity without it being tied to any particular application. That is, I basically would like to extend the already present feature of calling up applications according to their place in the sidebar, beyond the 0 allowed by default.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I still don't understand. Now, Super+0-9 (plus s and t) are two-keypress shortcuts. To add more shortcuts using letters, you would follow the instructions at the link. Don't worry about your English either, it's fine.(¿mejor de mi Espanol, no?). Try rephrasing or just post it in Spanish below the English, someone might translate better for you. It happens here from time to time.

Comment: Actually, I don't know Spanish, ;-). Besides English, only Maltese and Italian.

Comment: I'll try using the instructions in the link above and see if that works, though I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm an idiot, sorry.

Comment: No worries, we all make mistakes!

Comment: I checked the option offered in the linked question, however that doesn't give me what I want and I believe I can cope with the situation as is. Surely, it would be handier if I could go beyond Super+0 when more applications are open and showing in the Unity sidebar. Perhaps this could be submitted to those responsible for its development?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Sounds more like you are requesting for a feature in Unity according to your last comment.Take a look at _[What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)_