# How do I turn off Hold Super for shortcut list?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I like to map changing desktops to Super + Arrow keys, but in the newest version of Unity it seems to show up a keyboard shortcut list, even after I start clicking the arrow keys.  Is there any way to turn off the shortcut list pop up?  Or do I just need to change my mappings?

EDIT: It also appears to not like to close the workspace manager when the Super key is let go, I'm not sure if this is an issue because I switched from 2D to default, or by upgrading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have compizconfig-settings-manager A.K.A. CCSM(installable from Apt-get or software centre) then launch it and go to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" and then to "Experimental" and then uncheck the "enable shortcut display". Hope this helps!

- [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key)