# Unity plugin is swalling SUPER+P keybindings

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz

I am trying to bind a custom command to the key binding SUPER+P. I found that it doesn't work when the Unity plugin is enabled in the CompizConfig settings manager, but it *does* work when Unity is disabled.

All the keybindings listed in the Unity plugin settings are disabled. But it seems as though SUPER+P is being bound regardless.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can get SUPER+P to run my command without disabling Unity plugin?

Comment: This link might have some helpful info. [Unbinding super from unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148975/cannot-unbind-super-key-from-unity)

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Ubuntu you are using?  This is probably a duplicate questions, which is answered here

[How to disable global <Super>-p shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68463/how-to-disable-global-super-p-shortcut)

You can also find info on how to take control of **Super+p** here: --> [A hack to rescue Super+P from gnome-settings-daemon](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-314.html)  One of the answers in the above link uses this solution.