# How can I quickly see a list of the keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, system-settings

For example, to see which keys switch between multiple terminal windows.

I'm trying to use the keyboard more and the mouse less.

If I have multiple windows open I can use <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between them.

By default it starts to select the 'next' application window but I found that if I hold it down for 2 seconds it will stay on the terminal window and allow me to switch between terminal windows.  This is what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to be able to switch between windows - either through the multi-pane approach above or by cycling through the windows - without using the above approach with the 2 second delay.

It would be great if there was a way to do something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

I am not looking for split-window or tab windows or tmux pane solutions.  I already use these and this is a separate issue that I like to know if there is any options to address this need.

Keyboard manager settings shows the below but doesn't seem to help me.

[image]

Also keyboard shortcuts shows:

[image]

but <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f6</kbd> doesn't work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key or the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> key **only** for **2-3 seconds** brings up the "Keyboard Shortcuts" window that shows the system's keyboard shortcuts.

Combinations shown using <kbd>Super</kbd> key:

[image: shortcut overview screenshot]

Comment: Looks like the `Window` key is called the `Super` key based on your screenshot. I think I might start calling it that for even Macs.

Comment: This doesn't work for me; has this functionality changed in newer versions? Holding the super key does literally nothing at the moment. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @jhaagsma This didn't work for me either (Ubuntu 16.04), turns out that you have to enable the super key first on some systems. I just got myself a new Dell XPS 13 and [this help article on how to enable the super button](http://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/how12108/how-to-enable-the-ubuntu-super-key-on-dell-oem-ubuntu-installations?lang=en) did the trick for me. **Basically, if the super/windows key doesn't open the dash, it doesn't show the keyboard shortcuts either.**

Comment: what about Ubuntu 18.04? AFAIK it was Unity feature

Comment: BTW, on Mac, it is the Command Key in default

Comment: This solution is probably outdated, as it doesn't seem to work with never versions of ubuntu (18.04.04 here).

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Didn't work for me either on 20.04, but it turned out they were changed to CTRL+SUPER+UP in the settings menu (not sure if I did that myself, or if some upgrade script did that). To restore the default behavior, go to setting menu -> keyboard shortcuts, go to the windows section and press the cross next to 'maximize window' to reset to the default.

Answer (score 1):

My old answer doesn't work anymore.

new answer:  use this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en

although it is not for my system so doesn't show any cutomizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch between windows immediately. It's more ordered than the default method but doesn't show you a list of windows.

Answer (score 0):

To show the keyboard shortcuts window, press (and hold) the <kbd>super</kbd> key (on my keyboard, this key had a Windows logo printed on it).

Comment: probably outdated information (see above)